# How can I change the connection descriptor used by Oracle Enterprise Manager?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I've recently changed the `SERVICE_NAME` of my 11g database and Enterprise Manager can no longer connect to it:

> 2014-01-08 10:36:06,047 [HTTPThreadGroup-3] ERROR eml.OMSHandshake
>   processFailure.806 - OMSHandshake failed.(AGENT URL =
>   https://Test9.lab.nyc-14.knoa.com:3938/emd/main)(ERROR =
>   INTERNAL_ERROR)(CAUSE =java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the
>   connection with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not
>   currently know of service requested in connect descriptor The
>   Connection descriptor used by the client was:
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=Test9.lab.nyc-14.knoa.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test9.lab.nyc-14.knoa.com))))

The `SERVICE_NAME` in there is indeed the old one. I've updated `NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora` but that didn't fix it. Where does Enterprise Manager read the connection descriptor from?

Comment: Have you changed the `listener.ora` on the DB server?

Comment: listener.ora does not seem to have a SERVICE_NAME. As far as I know, the DB server dynamically registers its service name with the listener at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine, I found the connect descriptor in:

```
C:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\Test9.lab.nyc-14.knoa.com_test9\sysman\config\emoms.properties
```

looking like this:

```
oracle.sysman.eml.mntr.emdRepConnectDescriptor=(DESCRIPTION\=(ADDRESS_LIST\=(ADDRESS\=(PROTOCOL\=TCP)(HOST\=Test9.lab.nyc-14.knoa.com)(PORT\=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA\=(SERVICE_NAME\=test9)))
```

Changing the SERVICE_NAME here fixed the error I encountered even though it was not enough the get my Enterprise Manager back in shape.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing because you haven't specified what version of OEM you're using.

If you're using OEM 12C, go to the DB home then click on "Oracle Database", "Target Setup", "Monitoring Configuration".  You can change the SID there.

Comment: I'm using 11g R2. The problem is with the SERVICE_NAME, not the SID. Also in the OEM for 11g I can't follow your sequence of links. OEM is not yet functional to use it for configuration. I'm assuming the connection descriptor is read from a file or something.

Comment: Can you use emca to reconfigure it?  e.g. like this: ./emca -config dbcontrol db (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/emca.htm#CIAFCBIB - using EMCA to configure Enterprise Manager)

Comment: I did, but that ran into a ClassNotFoundException. I guess this installation is toasted.