# ClassNotFoundException when trying to deconfig Oracle Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, enterprise-manager

The Enterprise Manager for my Oracle 11.2 installation doesn't work anymore as described in [How can I change the connection descriptor used by Oracle Enterprise Manager?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56372/how-can-i-change-the-connection-descriptor-used-by-oracle-enterprise-manager) and I tried to re-configure it using the instructions [here](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/oracle-architecture-configuration/changing-windows-hostname-and-oracle-enterprise-manager/). However, the deconfig command runs into a ClassNotFoundException:

```
C:\Users\bcalmac>emca -deconfig dbcontrol db -repos drop

STARTED EMCA at Jan 10, 2014 12:05:04 PM
EM Configuration Assistant, Version 11.2.0.0.2 Production
Copyright (c) 2003, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter the following information:
Database SID: test9
Listener port number: 1521
Password for SYS user:
Password for SYS user: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HTTPClient/ProtocolNotSuppException
        at oracle.sysman.emd.targetIntg.agent.AgentTargetInstaller.<clinit>(AgentTargetInstaller.java:235)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.target.TargetManager.getAgentTargetInstaller(TargetManager.java:1008)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.target.TargetManager.getLocalHost(TargetManager.java:1033)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.ParamsManager.getLocalHost(ParamsManager.java:1037)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.ParamsManager.getHost(ParamsManager.java:3020)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.DatabaseChecks.validateUserCredentials(DatabaseChecks.java:1066)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.ParamsManager.validatePassword(ParamsManager.java:3417)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.promptForData(EMConfigAssistant.java:701)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.promptForParams(EMConfigAssistant.java:2979)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.displayWarnsAndPromptParams(EMConfigAssistant.java:3008)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.getDisplayAndPromptWarnsParms(EMConfigAssistant.java:3033)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.performConfiguration(EMConfigAssistant.java:1397)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.statusMain(EMConfigAssistant.java:574)
        at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.main(EMConfigAssistant.java:522)
```

In what jar is this class, so I can copy it over from another Oracle installation?

Answer (score -1):

**Copy /oui/jlib/http_client.jar to
/user_projects/domains/GCDomain/lib/**

Comment: The target directory will be different on @BogdanCalmac's machine, not least because he's using Windows.